# UnInstalling chrome extension using selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

One of my automation test cases is to uninstall chrome extension and reinstall it again and check whether values stored by extension are cleared.Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Have your tried [this](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/6-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium)? That worked for me on the silenium test case I used for a chrome plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt talk about uninstalling chrome programmatically